# Laravel interventation image break images on save method

Tags: php, image, laravel-5, intervention

I'm on laravel 5.4...

I need to upload some images and make a thumbnail for every single image and save thumbnail in another name.

Well, upload works fine but when I try to resize images and make thumbnail using `intervention` package, saved thumbnail seems to be broken.

Please take a look to this picture:
[image: show images]

This is  my code:

```
    $image = $request->file('ax');
    $imagename = mt_rand(999, 999999) . "_" . time() . "_" . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $width = $img->width();
    $height = $img->height();

    $img->resize(200, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path('storage/' . $token) . '/' . $imagename);
```

and if I change my `storage path` to :

```
Storage::url($token)
```

I will get an error says:

> Can't write image data to path (/storage/ajxpmXZF2rPfyOu39CcdEgC7Gpi5AlGviysrug88/872130_1496335864_jpg)

Would you please help me to find my problem...?

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 0):

Change the storage path of image accordingly. If the image upload fails, handle it gracefully instead of the exception here.

```
    $image = $request->file('ax');

    if (!$image->isValid()) {
        throw new \Exception('Failed to upload image.');
    }

    $imagename = mt_rand(999, 999999) . "_" . time() . "_" . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $img = Image::make($image);

    $img->resize(200, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

    $img->save(public_path("storage/{$token}/{$imagename}"));
```